# Display a popup from background service in android

Tags: java, android, service, popupwindow

This is a use case for an application I am developing. There is a background service which runs and scans for signals from beacons, and when a particular event is registered, it should display a popup to the user even when the app is not running on foreground. The popup should be closeable from the screen itself.

Also please guide me to a source, if there are any other preferred way of doing this other than a popup window.

```
@Override
public void onEvent(BluetoothDeviceEvent event) {
  //This event is working and displaying the notifications
  Utilities.buildNotification();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: There is no way to create dialog in service. better to navigate in activity and display dailog using activity context over there

Comment: U should register broadcast from activity and from service send result back to BR and in _onReceive_ method show your dialog.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I am pretty new to Android development. Can you direct me onto some guides where I can learn more about?

Comment: Why not simply use Notifications? It does everything you want (except being a Dialog) and your method already suggests that you want to use one.

Comment: What I want to display is a full screen image. Something like a advertisement. That cannot be done using notifications right?

Comment: Nope it cant. If you want full screen you might want to start an Activity right from the Service. Add the 'Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK' the the Intent thats starts the Activity and it should pop up every time the event is received. But people tend to hate applications that randomly spawn Activities out of context. I would not release an app with such a solution to the public. But thats just my opinion.

Comment: Hmm.. Thank you @GPuschka for the guide :) I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem statement can be solved using widgets.

> Widgets are an essential aspect of home screen customization. You can imagine them as "at-a-glance" views of an app's most important data and functionality that is accessible right from the user's home screen. Users can move widgets across their home screen panels, and, if supported, resize them to tailor the amount of information within a widget to their preference....[more on android developer site here](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/widgets.html)

Here is nice sample tutorial
[Sample Android widget tutorial](http://www.androidauthority.com/create-simple-android-widget-608975/)

Comment: Are you sure about this?

Comment: The probllem statement says "There is a background service which runs and scans for signals from beacons, and when a particular event is registered, it should display a popup to the user even when the app is not running on foreground. The popup should be closeable from the screen itself.".....notification is one way of doing stuff but I feel widgets provide more handle on the UI aspect....however I am just assuming the level of interaction is pretty complex.

Comment: Widgets are not I am looking for. Something similar to an activity which can be closed from the homescreen itself is what I am hoping to do. Thanks anyway. :)